# NullReferenceException When Trying To Reach REST Endpoint

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have a database management class which has multiple methods to reach different endpoints on a REST API. Everything appears to be working except for this one issue. When the app is started, I am trying to reach an endpoint the exact same way I reach the other endpoints. For some reason, this one completely breaks the app and throws a NullReferenceException without any information.

I have confirmed that the client is not null, and the URL and endpoint works fine in Postman. I honestly have no idea what would be causing this exception, and the fact that it doesn't show any information about the exception just makes it worse.

```
private async void InitDatabase()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("System?Guid=1");
        string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        SysParams sysParams = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SysParams>(responseString);
    }
```

The error occurs when the first line is executed where client.GetAsync is called.
[image: Output]
[image: Error Page]
[image: Client Inspection]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Sach Thanks for the comment, but I know what a NullReferenceException is, I'm trying to figure out what's causing it in my situation.

Comment: The linked duplicate will guide how to figure out what's causing it in your situation

Comment: I'm still having trouble finding the error. I have surrounded the method with a try catch yet it doesn't catch it. The program still breaks without any stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, it started working after I had made the call without awaiting it.